# Display Large Image in form of chunks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a google map sort of application that loads the image asynchronously from back end. I just want to know where should i start and how to proceed in that direction. The image has to be loaded into browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start looking at imagemagick and its "convert".

Comment: i want the image to be rendered at runtime

Comment: You can use imagemagick from server-side scripts, PHP for example. There is a whole lot of libs and helpers. Look here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php